# Iterative/recursive search of array

Tags: c, arrays, search, iteration

I want to write a search function that can recursively search an array of one or multiple elements: if multiple elements are "active", it should iterate through them; if there's only one, just only return that one element.
What I have so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 10
int GetNext(int curr);

typedef struct test_s {
    int actv;
} test_t;

static test_t now[NUM] = {0};

int main(void)
{
    int curr = 0;
    now[1].actv = 1;
    //now[2].actv = 1;
    //now[5].actv = 1;
    //now[9].actv = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        curr = GetNext(curr);
        printf("curr %d\n",curr);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}

int GetNext(int curr)
{
    ++curr; //increment index
    if (curr==NUM){
        curr = 0; //rollover
    }
   if (now[curr].actv ==1)
       return curr;
   else{
       for (;curr<NUM;curr++)
           if (now[curr].actv == 1)
               return curr;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Now, I don't want it to return -1 if there one or more active elements in the array... but only return -1 if none are active, otherwise it should start over at 0 (after reaching NUM-1). How do I best go about doing that?

Comment: If you don't want to return -1, don't `return -1;`, or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: what do you want to return/do instead of returning -1?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.... I'd want it to start over again at 0...and only return -1 if no elements are active

Comment: `curr` is uninitialized in main

Comment: @smac89 you're right, I fixed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the reset to 0 inside of your loop, then have the loop test to see if you're back where you started.

```
int GetNext(int curr)
{
    int start = curr;
    do {
      ++curr; //increment index
      if (curr==NUM){
          curr = 0; //rollover
      }
      if (now[curr].actv ==1)
          return curr;
   } while (curr != start);
   return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
int GetNext(int curr) {
    int start = curr;

    for (curr++; curr != start; curr++) {
        if (curr >= NUM){
            curr = 0;
        }

        if (now[curr].actv == 1) {
            return curr;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```